# Ext JS 6 - sortchange event for gridcolumn not fired

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I want to capture the sorting change happening in the grid column and update a boolean in the grid. I tried the following code in this [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1p25).

But when I click on the column headers for sorting, the contents are sorted, but the sortchange event listener is not triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You must put the sortchange in the grid's listener instead of the column's listener

```
listener: {
                    sortchange : function()
                    {
                       your code here
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot. It works :) But I have one doubt. GridColumn also says it exposes the same event. Any idea on why it is not working with grid column?